# Usecase of redux over normal state mechanism in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am developing react native application. I came across redux for state management of the application.

Suppose I have welcome tour in my application which should be one time view activity. I can save this in normal state and check in my component.

This can be doable using redux too, then how redux is different than normal state. Any use case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redux in React Native is no different than Redux in a normal React application so all advice on Redux vs local state apply.

Quoting Redux docs:

> **Using local component state is fine.** As a developer, it is your job to
>   determine what kinds of state make up your application, and where each
>   piece of state should live. Find a balance that works for you, and go
>   with it.
>
> Some common rules of thumb for determining what kind of data should be
>   put into Redux:
>
> - Do other parts of the application care about this data?
> - Do you need to be able to create further derived data based on this original data?
> - Is the same data being used to drive multiple components?
> - Is there value to you in being able to restore this state to a given point in time (ie, time travel debugging)?
> - Do you want to cache the data (ie, use what's in state if it's already there instead of re-requesting it)?

Quoting Dan Abramov, the author of Redux:

> If you’re just learning React, don’t make Redux your first choice.
>   Instead learn to think in React. Come back to Redux if you find a real
>   need for it, or if you want to try something new. But approach it with
>   caution, just like you do with any highly opinionated tool.

and my favourite:

> **The rule of thumb is: do whatever is less awkward.**

Sources:

- http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#do-i-have-to-put-all-my-state-into-redux-should-i-ever-use-reacts-setstate
- https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367
- https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287#issuecomment-175351978

Comment: Is the same data being used to drive multiple components? - Can't we save it in normal state and get it in other components ?

Comment: We can, absolutely. The reason behind this question is likely the fact that while passing the state as props to multiple components is relatively easy, it can get out of hand very quickly. Personally I wouldn't bother with Redux until you find passing the state around too convoluted.

Comment: So in case of normal state I have to pass it into props right ? and in case of redux it is not required to pass it into props ? it makes available in all components ?

Comment: Yes, normally you pass the state down using props. In Redux you still need to map the state to props for each component but the main difference is that the state comes from the Redux store rather than your parent component so it's much easier to access it anywhere in your application. This comes at a price of quite a lot of boilerplate code though.

Comment: Do you have an example of redux sharing data between multiple components ? any link

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your question but if you're after an example of different components subscribing to the same store/data it's as simple as using the same mapping code in both. The components might be anywhere in your app, and still share the same state in between them. There's a superb and free series on Egghead if you want to dig in further: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux